# Почему не все картинки загружаются через GitHub Pages?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scss

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, почему не все картинки загружаются через Pages
Ссылка на репозиторий https://github.com/Tetiana-Naumchuk/Online_Shop
Ссылка на Pages https://tetiana-naumchuk.github.io/Online_Shop/

Comment: не все пути введут прямо в директорию с картинкой, просто укажите перед ссылкой "." - ./dist/.. .

Comment: Спасибо большое)))